# How to say “similarly" as a transition?

Tags: vocabulary

I've tried to use the transition "similarly" multiple times in Chinese, but I've gotten mixed feedback on how I should say it.

I've been told I should say "同样的“ and not 同样  like "John 这几天因为党军的原因不会来上课“ 同样的， Clarence 因为 Navy 的原因也不会来上课”.

Recently, however  I wrote "同样的，《丈夫》的婚姻 也有一些性别歧视的因素。", which got changed to "同样".

Could anyone comment on which is preferred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there is no different meaning between 同样的 and 同样 when we use them to connect two sentences.

However, in my experience, 同样的 is used to connect two short sentences, like your first example. Tom swims well, 同样的, John can swim with three styles.

同样 is used start a new sentence. Tom is not rich, but he is really a nice guy. 同样, even John is disabled, but he try his best to take care of himself and help more people.

In speaking Chinese, you can ignore this. Because the pronunciation of 的 in 同样的 can speak like the “d” in yard.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following
...的原因不会来上课， Clarence 也同样的因为 Navy 的原因也不会来上课..
Grammatically, the second sentence seems correct to me.

同样的 is usually for linkage followed by more description. 同样 means similar, but it a more formal word. I don't see it use in conversations unlike its contrary counter part '不同'.

Before you start stringing sentences, maybe you should try to improve the vocab first. Free apps like HSK Locker with flashcard and quiz features can help familiarize yourself with the words.